# Address validation via Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I want to send an address via Google API and get a response if this is a valid or wrong address. If it's a wrong address the response will include the reason (e.g. wrong zip code, wrong state etc.)

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Not it seems that it is possible: https://mapsplatform.google.com/maps-products/address-validation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Maps APIs are not intended for address validation. They do, however, provide a variety of other services including geolocation, directions, distance calculation, and much more. For a list of APIs as well as what they can do for you please check out the API Picker here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is now an Address Validator API under the Google Maps Platform
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/requests-validate-address

From their documentation:

> Address validation request
>
> Validate an address by sending a POST
> request to the validateAddress method:
>
> https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key=YOUR_API_KEY
> Pass a JSON body to the request defining the address to validate:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
  "address": {
    "regionCode": "US",
    "locality": "Mountain View",
    "addressLines": ["1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"]
  }
}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
"https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```